# Why are the return types of .NET's System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize methods nullable when it doesn't return null?

Tags: c#, json, .net, deserialization, system.text.json

Consider .NET 6's [System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0) method and its many overloads.

Each one returns either `object?` or `TValue?` which indicates that `null` could be returned.  However, the documentation states that in the event of any error, an exception is thrown.  Moreover, it also states that a valid value is returned (if an exception isn't thrown).  Nowhere does it state that `null` could be returned.  And in my experience of using it, `null` is never returned.

(The nullable return type is a problem if you turn on "nullability" in your project, because the compiler then starts warning you that the returned value *could be null* - which in my experience (and according to the documentation) just isn't true.  It's this sort of thing that has me scurrying to switch nullability off again.  I know I can suppress the warning, but I don't think that's the point.)

Is the documentation lacking?  Can the methods really return null?  If they can't, then why do we have nullable return types?

Comment: `null` is valid JSON.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- `TValue? Deserialize<TValue>` is just a wrapper for `Object? Deserialize(type: typeof(TValue))`.
- When `#nullable` annotations were added to C# 8.0, the `System.Type` type was not extended with support for those annotations.

  - Therefore, it is not possible for a generic-type in C# to know (at runtime) if a generic-type-parameter's concrete type-argument is a nullable-reference-type or a non-nullable-reference-type.

    - <sub>(This doesn't apply to `Nullable<T>`, of course)</sub>
  - **UPDATE**: [In .NET 6 it is now possible to use runtime reflection to inspect nullable annotations with `NullabilityInfoContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.nullabilityinfocontext?view=net-6.0).
- So, at runtime, a call-site for `Deserialize<TValue>()` using either `TValue := MyClass?` or `TValue := MyClass` will behave identically because the `Deserialize` method has no idea if `MyClass` has the `?` annotation or not.

  - The `Deserialize<TValue>` method only knows if `TValue` is a reference-type or not (via `typeof(TValue)`).
- Therefore, if you instruct `JsonSerializer` to deserialize the string `"null"` (which *is valid JSON*) *and* if `TValue` is a reference type, then it will return `null`.

  - ...*even if* your `TValue` doesn't have `?`. Remember that `JsonSerializer` doesn't (and cannot) know that!
- Which is why the method's static return-type has the `?` annotation, because if it didn't then it would be incorrectly asserting it never returns `null`.

---

It can be argued that `JsonSerialize`'s designers *could* have added some more methods that allowed callers to statically assert non-null-ness, but they didn't, but you can if you really want to:

Like so:

```
public static TValue DeserializeNonNullObject<TValue>( String json )
    where TValue : class
{
    TValue? orNull = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TValue>( json );
    return orNull ?? throw new JsonException( "Expected deserialized object to be non-null, but encountered null." );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  This has helped me understand many things.  I did not know - or forgot - that "null" was valid JSON.

Answer (score 5):

According to RFC 7159 “null” (and “true” and “false”) will be valid JSON text. However, empty string is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks!  And thanks to @Dai!  I get it now.  And I tested it out and confirmed the result: `var x = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Test>("null"); // returns null`.  Finally I understand.  So maybe I really should switch on "nullability" and pay attention to the warnings!  (Up until now I always assumed that null just wouldn't be returned.  I was wrong.)